# android manipulate background color

Tags: android

I am trying to make an app with a simple design.
I gave the entire layout an orange background but i want the top part (above the fragment to be white)

I tried to change background for the title, but there are these little margin lines below and above it still white, how can I change it?
I tryed changing the margin but it didn't work out

(see the image)
[Image][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwNnL.png
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwNnL.png

Here is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#e5a511">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Location Weather"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    tools:context="com.tos.nav42.memorableplaces.MapsActivity"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/tempTV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/descriptionTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tempTV"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tempTV"
    android:capitalize="none"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: please post your xml file code?

Comment: i edited my post and added the code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove white background from textview. You can either remove background property or set it to transparent color i.e #00FFFFFF.
Change your code this way:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Location Weather"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF" />
```

You can read more about how to change background color here:

https://medium.com/@duaaawan/how-to-change-background-color-in-android-app-3d4dea54f35f

---

If you want to remove space above and below your title text.
Change your textview code from

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Location Weather"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

To

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Location Weather"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```